# Replace custom list search with Java lambda expressions

Tags: java

I am looking to replace the following code with Java lambda expressions.In the below case I need to come out the loop if the match is found and also set boolean to true in order to assert a condition

```
      Long teamId;
    boolean matchFound = false;
    List<WorkflowSubscriptions> workflowSubscriptionsList = fetchSubscriptions();
    for (WorkflowSubscriptions workflowSubscriptions : workflowSubscriptionsList) {
        for (WorkflowCompositeInfo workflowCompositeInfo : workflowSubscriptions.getWorkflowCompositeInfo()) {
            if (workflowCompositeInfo.getId() > 0 && workflowCompositeId == workflowCompositeId.intValue()) {
                teamId = Long.valueOf(workflowSubscriptions.getId());
                matchFound = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!matchFound) {
        throw new CustomParameterizedException("Workflow does not have valid subscriptions");
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried it before asking? What have you come up with?

Comment: The below code I prepared was for the one level of list. Now I have a list in side a list  StreamSupport.stream(Optional.ofNullable(rwpSubscriptions).orElse(Collections.emptyList()))
            .filter(s->s.getCompositeId().equals(workflowCompositeId))
            .findFirst()
            .map(s->s.getTeamId())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new CustomParameterizedException("Workflow does not have a valid subscription"))

Comment: @YassinHajaj posting for your reference

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
fetchSubscriptions().stream()
    .filter(p -> w.getId() > 0 && workflowCompositeId == w.intValue())
    .limit(1)
    .forEach(w -> {teamId = Long.valueOf(w); matchFound = true;} );
```

**UPDATE**

To avoid errors about modifying a final variable. You can simply create a value class:

```
public class MyValue {
    public boolean matchFound;
    public Long teamId;
}
```

Then:

```
final MyValue value = new MyValue();

fetchSubscriptions().stream()
    .filter(p -> w.getId() > 0 && workflowCompositeId == w.intValue())
    .limit(1)
    .forEach(w -> {value.teamId = Long.valueOf(w); value.matchFound = true;}  );

// Here, find your data in value.teamId and value.matchFound
```

Comment: Thanks much let me try and come back. Initially I had one level of list but now as I have posted I have two StreamSupport.stream(Optional.ofNullable(rwpSubscriptions).orElse(Collections.emptyList()))
            .filter(s->s.getCompositeId().equals(workflowCompositeId))
            .findFirst()
            .map(s->s.getTeamId())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new CustomParameterizedException("Workflow does not have a valid subscription"))

Comment: Also I am using Java 8 just for development. I need to use back port version of Java 8 and implement the same. Just want to know whether the above will work on back port version of Java 8 ?

Comment: It really depends on the backport implementation. But there's no reason it should not. It complies with the API

Comment: I get an error saying that I cannot modify the variables that are not final? How am I to go around this. I need to return a long value here(teamId) also assign boolean(matchFound) true and also break out of the loop when the match is found

Comment: you could simply make a custom object with a long and a boolean attribute. Make that object final. I'll update the code for you.